# Manage external image in readonly with Intervention Image / Image cache

Tags: image, laravel

I use a crud system for Laravel [Sleeping Owl](http://sleeping-owl.github.io/) that uses Image Intervention for image managing.

Thing is all is done to manage local pics, but I just need to see pics in list, I will never do crud on pics.

Is there a way to display external pics with that system ( http://my-external-domain.com/images/mypic.png )???

Comment: Could you be more specific with the question? because so far i dont understand why is it so difficult to display a pic from another domain

Comment: Your question is way too broad. At least post the code that is responsible for managing the images?